# call/invoke a method in php class using exec

Tags: php, exec

In php suppose there is a class named as 'test_class' in `test.php` with two methods: `method_1` and `method_2`.

This is my `test.php` file:

```
    class test_class  
    { 
       function method_1
       { .......   }

       function method_2
       { .......   }

    }
```

Now, using the "exec" command from other php file, I want to run only the method_1 in the test_class.

I want to know how this can be achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=run+php+code+asynchronously

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=run+php+code+in+background

Answer (score 1):

You can do this instead:

```
include_once 'test.php'; // correct path if needed
$test = new test_class();
// call method1
$test->method_1();
```

Comment: i want all the code in that methods to run in background., so that is the reason i want it like that

Comment: @SriVishnuTotakura: Check out php job queueu: http://stut.net/2009/05/29/php-job-queue/

Comment: that is kinda similar problem with a solution., thanks., i will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)?

`exec` isn't meant to call methods, it's used to:

> exec — Execute an external program

Comment: i know that exec is for executing a external program., i thought there could be a way for calling a method in a php file by sending something as parameters.

Comment: Please explain why you would want to do that, maybe there are easier ways.

Comment: i am developing a web service in which it checks for updates in a interval of time from other servers, so i need to invoke this script of checking updates and need to stop it or kill it whenever the user don't want to receive the updates. i thought of cron jobs but, setting the cron jobs needs to be manual. when number of users increase for me, i cannot schedule a job manually for each one of them.

Comment: You can queue the user actions in a database and execute those one by one with a cron job.

Comment: what is said is fine for a few number of users., what about a lodge number of users, i wish to provide my users service without waiting time., but using a queue may cause little delay of service.